# Can a monster be leveled so high that it can't be skilled up?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

When I've fed smaller monsters to target monsters to raise them to max levels (for example, raising a Pengdra to level 10 so that it can be evolved into a 2nd-level Pengdra) I have often gotten the message "Maximum Level Reached" with an accompanying warning that I can't perform any more Power-Up Fusion.  It doesn't usually happen when I just reach the maximum number of experience points, but when I've gone over by some margin.

Skilling up a monster is done by Power-Up Fusion, and (except for Pys) there's no telling how many times you'll have to try before it's successful.  Does that mean that if I have a monster, say a Green Odin, at max level, and I keep feeding it monsters to try and skill up its active, I might hit a point where I can't try any more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to skill up monsters that are not enhance / evolution material until they are max skill. You do not "run out" of chances. You will just no longer benefit from experience at max level.